# Transitions vs keyframes on load

Tags: jquery, css, css-transitions, fullpage.js

I am using fullpage.js. and when i use the following the transitions occur on load and when i scroll to next section they reverse out, then when returning to section it animates in again:

```
.section-one .slide-one > .fp-tableCell h1,
.section-one .slide-one > .fp-tableCell p {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-1000px);
            transform: translateY(-1000px);
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition: opacity .66s ease-in-out,
                -webkit-transform .66s cubic-bezier(0.16, 0.68, 0.43, 0.99);
    transition: opacity .66s ease-in-out,
                -webkit-transform .66s cubic-bezier(0.16, 0.68, 0.43, 0.99);
    transition: transform .66s cubic-bezier(0.16, 0.68, 0.43, 0.99),
                opacity .66s ease-in-out;
    transition: transform .66s cubic-bezier(0.16, 0.68, 0.43, 0.99),
                opacity .66s ease-in-out,
                -webkit-transform .66s cubic-bezier(0.16, 0.68, 0.43, 0.99);
}

.section-one.active .slide-one.active > .fp-tableCell h1,
.section-one.active .slide-one.active > .fp-tableCell p {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
            transform: translateY(0);
    opacity: 1;
}

.section-one.active .slide-one.active > .fp-tableCell h1 {
    -webkit-transition-delay: .44s;
            transition-delay: .44s;
}

.section-one.active .slide-one.active > .fp-tableCell p {
    -webkit-transition-delay: .22s;
            transition-delay: .22s;
}

.section-one.active .slide-one.active > .fp-tableCell p + p {
    -webkit-transition-delay: 0s;
            transition-delay: 0s;
}
```

but when i use animate.css keyframes and "animation: name;" it loads once, does not reverse on page leave and when you come back to the page it also does not animate:

```
.section-one .slide-one > .fp-tableCell h1 {
    animation: bounceInLeftM 3s;

}
.section-one .slide-one > .fp-tableCell h2{
    animation: bounceInRightM 3s;
}
.section-one .slide-one > .fp-tableCell h3{
    animation: growIn 3s;
}

.section-one .slide-one > .fp-tableCell p, a, #slogon, .linkblock {
animation: flipInX 1s;}

.section-one.active .slide-one.active > .fp-tableCell h1 {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
    transform: translateX(0);
    opacity: 1;
}
.section-one.active .slide-one.active > .fp-tableCell h2 {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
    transform: translateX(0);
    opacity: 1;
}
.section-one.active .slide-one.active > .fp-tableCell h3 {
    animation: growIn 3s;
}
.section-one.active .slide-one.active > .fp-tableCell p, span, #slogon, .linkblock {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
            transform: translateY(0);
    opacity: 1;
}

.section-one.active .slide-one.active > .fp-tableCell h1 {
    -webkit-transition-delay: .44s;
            transition-delay: .44s;
}
.section-one.active .slide-one.active > .fp-tableCell h2 {
    -webkit-transition-delay: .44s;
            transition-delay: .44s;
}
.section-one.active .slide-one.active > .fp-tableCell p, span, #slogon, .linkblock {
    -webkit-transition-delay: .22s;
            transition-delay: .22s;
}

.section-one.active .slide-one.active > .fp-tableCell  {
    -webkit-transition-delay: 0s;
            transition-delay: 0s;
}
```

Interested in knowing how these are being handled differently and how to control the behaviour.

Comment: Keyframes run once on load, your other animation will be applied when you do something with them, it best to apply transitions by adding / removing a class with JS that way you have control when they apply

Comment: Yeap, @saj is right. Just remove and add the animation each time you want it to play.